# How to handle the error xhr.js in React app when I use axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to handle the error. Below are attached the code from: App.js, unsplash.js and component ErrorBoundery.js. I cannot stop error from displaying in red in console.log. The website itself works fine. I have been trying to figure it out for a day. I do not know what is wrong.

Of course the error occurs when I try to search for a pictures by word that is not related to any picture tag in unsplash API. The error message looks like this:

xhr.js:210 GET https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?per_page=21&page=1 400

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import unsplash from "../api/unsplash";
import PhotoList from "./PhotoList";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import { AppProvider } from "./AppContext";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import words from "./data/words.json";
import { ErrorBoundary } from "./ErrorBoundery";

export default function App() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [numPage, setNumPage] = useState(1);

  let suggestion = words[0].words;

  async function handleSearchSubmit(name) {
    const response = await unsplash
      .get("/search/photos", {
        params: { query: name, per_page: 21, page: numPage },
      })
      .catch((err) => {    
        if (err.response) {
          setErrors(err.response.data.errors);          
        } else if (err.request) {
          console.log(err.request);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      });

    try {
      setPhotos(response.data.results);
    } catch {
      console.log(
        `Message: there are no images available related to this name`
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AppProvider>
        <Helmet>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>Via Images</title>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
          />
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="Website for anyone interested in exploring the world via images."
          />
        </Helmet>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Modal />
          <Search
            suggestions={suggestion}
            onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}
            numPage={numPage}
            setNumPage={setNumPage}
          />
          <PhotoList errors={errors} photos={photos} />
          <Footer />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

unsplash.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.unsplash.com",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Client-ID IN-THIS-PLACE-IS-MY-KEY",
  },
})
```

ErrorBoundary.js

```
import React from "react";

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false, error: null };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true, error };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log("Boundery: ", error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <div>Something went wrong: {this.state.error.message}</div>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your error is unhandled because you try to combine then() with async await, so your catch() is never called. Try to surround it with one try/catch

```
async function handleSearchSubmit(name) {
  try {
    const response = await unsplash.get("/search/photos", {
      params: { query: name, per_page: 21, page: numPage },
    })
    if(response.data.results.length > 0){
      setPhotos(response.data.results);
    }else{
      console.log(
      `Message: there are no images available related to this name`
      );
    }
 } catch (error) {
   if (err.response) {
     setErrors(err.response.data.errors);          
   } else if (err.request) {
     console.log(err.request);
   } else {
     console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed. I have tried it before but I tried once again and it is still displayed an error